# Use preferences from the user to calculate with

Tags: flutter

Don't understand all those explanations on the internet about SHARED PREFERENCES in Flutter and I am a little (little is not true) frustrated after searching and trying for three days. So I am calling out here for my hero.

I am working at my first app in Flutter. It is for calculate volume in weight users need for their project.

I have 4 screens, actived by a bottom-bar. 1 Screen is the Setting screen, where users can put their (1)mixing ratio, (2)the weight of the liquid and (3) the Boolean if they are measuring on weight(gr) of volume (ml). If they are using volume, option 2 is not necessary  is then hidden.

I want them to fill that as their settings. These settings I need for the formula on one of the other pages. If they fill in nothing, I have default values. I don't want that they have to fill in these settings every time but just once. Or twice if they use another kind of liquid. :-)

I have tried the SQFLITE package but I think the package SHARED PREFERENCES is what I need. I have watched all those video's on YouTube, I have googled and read and tried a lot of items, but I still don't get it what if have to do and where I have put the code. It always seems that if I retype what the experts are typing that I am the only one who get failure.

YES, I AM A BEGINNER (You all were once) and I am struggling with this topic now. 
My questions to you:
1. Is the package SHARED PREFERENCES the best solution for my app?
2. Where do I put the setting for writing the database.
3. How do I place a default value for the first time in this database.
4. Is it possible to set a value on the Setting screen, and get the value on another page, without using the Navigation (because I use a bottom-bar).

When you read to the end: THANK YOU!

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'constants.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class SettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SettingsPageState createState() => SettingsPageState();
}

class SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {
  int mixingRatio = 50;
  int liquidGravity = 115;
  bool weight = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

 Future<int> _getIntFromSharedPref() async {
   final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   final mixingRatio = prefs.getInt('mixingRatio');
   if (mixingRatio == null) {
     return 50;
   }
    return mixingRatio;
  }

  Future<void> _resetMixingRatio() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setInt('mixingRatio', 50);
}

   -----------------

                          onPressed: () {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            weight = true;
                            weightOrVolume = 'GR';
                          },
                        );
                      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions.

1. > Is the package SHARED PREFERENCES the best solution for my app?

For saving settings, surely this is the best package.

2. > Where do I put the setting for writing the database.

You can save the settings anywhere using `SharedPreference` instance like:

```
sharedPrefs.putInt("key", 10);
```

3. > How do I place a default value for the first time in this database

You can get it using dart syntax `??`

```
int savedValue = sharedPrefs.getInt("key") ?? 0; // default value will be 0
```

4. > Is it possible to set a value on the Setting screen, and get the value on another page, without using the Navigation.

Yes, you can do it, by either making global variable or retrieving it using `getInt` on the current screen.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me already a lot! I will let you know when I got it working!